# Google Maps Android API не принимает ключ

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

С горем по полам настроил и подключил google-play-services в Idea, приложение запускается, но выдает ошибку принятия ключа

```
ERROR/Google Maps Android API(10861): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.aldemstudio.zemeditor, API Key: AIzaSyANNfmn17ftKXnQjX7XP2mz1*******U, Certificate Fingerprint: CEA0518199322187F65EC72C5538A94E0C54FFE3
```

Вроде все верно сделал, но видно что нет, раз такое. Мой порядок действия был следующий (приложение запускаю на реальном устройстве прямо с IDE).
Вначале я создал хранилище ключей. Пробовал для дебага, не пошло на тестовом приложении, после создания релиз ключа - заработало. Поэтому на рабочем приложении делал сразу релизный. Делал так

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore "d:\keystore\zemeditor.keystore" -storepass xxxx -keypass xxxx -keyalg RSA -validity 14000
```

затем получаю отпечаток

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "d:\keystore\zemeditor.keystore"
```

На выходе получаю (некоторые цифры изменил)

```
Certificate fingerprints:
MD5:  91:D1:A2:DA:15:35:B8:C5:00:D1:96:11:21:76:5B:40
SHA1: 50:40:21:42:36:70:34:B2:30:4E:BD:DB:2B:CA:23:96:8A:86:26:50
SHA256: 50:10:C0:50:D8:2D:F0:E8:BC:DB:87:B5:8A:B6:75:26:29:2D:C4:F4:3F:14:85:5B:49:90:CE:CD:0D:9B:19:C0
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Version: 3
```

Копирую код SHA1 и иду в гугл консоль (уже Cloud console) и активирую **Google Maps Android API v2**

Затем в раздел "Register APP" и добавляю туда название Zemeditor, платформу выбираю Android и переключатель ставлю в **Accessing APIs directly from Android**
В Package name ввожу имя пакета com.aldemstudio.zemeditor
в SHA1 fingerprint код SHA1 выданный мне выше (50:40:21:42:36:70:34:B2:30:4E:BD:DB:2B:CA:23:96:8A:86:26:50)

в ответ получаю API KEY

```
AIzaSyANNfmn17ftKXnQjX7XP2mz1*********U
```

его прописываю в манифесте, вот он в окончательном варианте как выглядит

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.aldemstudio.zemeditor"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="9" />

<permission
android:name="com.aldemstudio.zemeditor.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.aldemstudio.zemeditor.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:debuggable="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyANNfmn17ftKXnQjX7XP2mz1*******U"/>

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name">

</activity>
<activity
android:name=".FacilitiesActivity"
android:label="Объекты">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
android:name=".EditorFacilityAction"
android:label="Добавление объекта"/>
<activity
android:name=".GoogleMapActivity"
android:label="Карта"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Запускается приложение, вижу серый экран с элементами зумирования и логотипом гугла и все. Ошибку из консоли привел в начале. Подскажите, пожалуйста, на каком шаге я допустил ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего при генирации sha1  если стояло еще что то работающея с java могут быть лаги- умен стояло IntellJ IDEA и Android Studio, у клиента IntellJ IDEA и какой то фреймворк флеш для android - тоже срерый экран и логи на ключ ругаются (

Снес все, поставил заново java - помогло )
не знаю из за чего такие ошибки, понимаю что решение бубнобразное но работает )

Comment: О-хо-хо, чего я только не ставил, пока карту пытался запустить. )))) Сейчас попробую на виртуалке поднять все это дело на чистую и глянуть

Comment: под виртуалкой не пробовал, сам на запуск карт два дня убил )) решеине хоть не айз но тратить еще недлю пока найду почему не правильно sha1 генерился как то не хочется )

Comment: Поставил на нетбук все с нуля - заработало. начал рыться в рабочем проекте попутно читая статьи и вспомнил что дебажный ключ выдается на год. Я удалил старое хранилище, в эклипс запустил пустой проект (он сам пересоздает дебаг.кейсторе, чего IDEA не делает, я так понял). заново получил дебаг кей через keytool, зарегил его, получил API KEY и все заработало. Еще предстоит выяснить почему release key не принимается, но это уже на будущее, программа минимум решена, карта запустилась.  gadfil спасибо за наводку, она подсказала решение и дала пищу для будущих размышлений и невероятных открытий ))

Comment: не знал про дебажный ключ, спасибо )

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что Вы использовали не тот SHA-1 ключ. 
В приложении есть разные ключи(для дебага, для релиза, для клиента, к примеру).
Вам надо использовать ключ для ДЕБАГА и тогда заработает.
+ внимательно читайте логи.
Ведь, если Вы будете использовать другой ключ(к примеру, для сервера) не будет даже никакой активности показываться в dashbord в console developers.